# Discord.js !kick Command says Access Denied despite me having the role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, my code will run through and won't give any errors. However, when I do `!kick @Player`, it says I don't have the correct permissions despite the fact that I do. Thoughts on why my role id is not valid or what may be causing this problem?

```
module.exports = {

    name: 'kick',
    description: "This is a kick command!",

    execute(message, args){

      if(message.member.roles.cache.has(('831942675565379654'))){
            
        // Easy way to get member object though mentions.
        var member= message.mentions.members.first();
        // Kick
        member.kick().then((member) => {
            // Successmessage
            message.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked :point_right: ");
        }).catch(() => {
             // Failmessage
            message.channel.send("Access Denied");
        });
}
       
       
    }
}
```

The error is as follows.

```
DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\knova\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)    
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\knova\OneDrive\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/guilds/797288597686190083/members/832295065099042886',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

Comment: Does the bot itself have the capability to kick members?

Comment: Your role ID should work fine.

Comment: It does have the capability. This role# is under server staff which the bot is apart of.

Comment: Well we know `member.kick()` fails since the catch function is executing

Comment: Then how should I go about fixing that? This is the best way my mind could put it into perspective.

Comment: Try actually logging the error. Replace your catch callback with `.catch(console.error)` to know why exactly it fails.

Comment: Just updated the question with the errror.

Comment: Error is self explanatory, your bot does not have the permissions to kick the member. Double check your role assignments and hierarchy.

Comment: Never mind, it was a matter of the way I called the role. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your bot doesen't have the necessary permission to kick out someone.
https://discordapi.com/permissions.html#8589934591
Go here and put your bot id.
Press on the bottom link, add your bot to your server and try again.
This should work.
For checking your bot id you can go on https://discord.com/developers/applications and press on your bot.
After that you can see your application id in the general informations.